# Calling parent method of extended variadic function in PHP?

Tags: php

Suppose we have

```php
class TestClass1 
{
    public function varFunc(string ...$str)
    {
    }
}

class TestClass2 extends TestClass1
{
    public function varFunc(string ...$str)
    {
        /* How do we perform this call? */
        return parent::varFunc($str);
    }
}
```

Calling TestClass2->varFunc() won't work since $str is passed as an array to TestClass1->varFunc() instead of a series of strings.  Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: `parent::varFunc(...$str)`…?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try with `...$str`?

```php
<?php

class TestClass1 
{
    public function varFunc(string ...$str)
    {   
        print_r($str);
    }   
}

class TestClass2 extends TestClass1
{
    public function varFunc(string ...$str)
    {   
        /* How do we perform this call? */
        return parent::varFunc(...$str);                                                                                                                                        
    }   
}

$a = new TestClass2();
$a->varFunc('asd');
```

---

```sh
$ php test.php 
Array
(
    [0] => asd
)
Array
(
    [0] => asd
)
```

Comment: Oh my god I'm going to blame this oversight on 2am coding xD.  Thanks!!!